# problems with binding data to data templates inside a busyindicator

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, busyindicator

i have some code in wpf in that i have used busyindicator and i set datatemplete now my problem is that i used mvvm pattern in my applicaton and i want to used busyindicator on that but i don't know how to binding textblock inside busyindicaor datatemplete.my code look like

```
<extended:BusyIndicator Name="_busyIndicator">
    <extended:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="4">
                <TextBlock Text="Downloading Email" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="Dhaval"/>
                <StackPanel Margin="4">
                    <TextBlock Text="Downloading message 4/10..."/>
                    <ProgressBar Value="40" Height="15" x:Name="Progress_Dhaval"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </extended:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Binding in a template or out of it is exactly the same, you just write `Text="{Binding YourProperty}"`  =)

Comment: it's not working while i am write normal binding.

Comment: I can't see any binding in your datatemplate

Comment: assume that textblock text property is bind now ..tell me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Binding with RelativeSource.

Add in your ViewModel this property:

```
        private string _busyText;
        public string BusyText
        {
            get { return _busyText; }
            set { _busyText = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => BusyText); }
        }
```

And change this line:

```
<TextBlock Text="Downloading message 4/10..."/>
```

on this one:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.BusyText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

Comment: That's What I want Thank You So much kmatyaszek.